# Triggering a nextflow pipeline upon data dump in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, automation, bioinformatics, nextflow

I am working on automating a pipeline for processing of NGS data and am a bit confused about what services are available and/or appropriate for this task. My ideal workflow can be seen below:

- Raw data comes off instrument and is stored in some S3 bucket
- **This dump is recognized by some service, could be airflow, cloudwatch, s3 invokes a lambda function, etc?**
- Whatever that trigger may be, it kicks off my nextflow workflow (runs my_workflow.nf) which processes the data and dumps it back to s3 for further downstream analysis

The question that I would really like help with is: What would be considered best practice or a suitable option for the bolded bullet point? What tool/service/utility could I use as a trigger to run a script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not familiar with AWS S3, but can you maybe use a watchpath (https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#watchpath) to keep an eye on the folder where your data gets dumped?

Comment: You can use S3 trigger to invoke a Lambda function. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html